# Remove postfix from artifactory path in SBT

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-plugin

I am updating scala version in my project from `scalaVersion := "2.11.12"` to `scalaVersion := "2.12.12"`
sbt version is 1.4.3.

I have a `"com.sksamuel.scapegoat" % "sbt-scapegoat" % "1.3.9"` plugin which is not getting resolved.

Following error -

`[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading com.sksamuel.scapegoat:sbt-scapegoat;sbtVersion=1.0;scalaVersion=2.12:1.3.9`

`[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sksamuel/scapegoat/sbt-scapegoat_2.12_1.0/1.3.9/sbt-scapegoat-1.3.9.pom`

Why `_2.12_1.0` gets added in postfix.

I have used SINGLE `%` in the plugin, so _2.12 should not add.

Also, where does `_1.0` come from?

What can be done to resolve this?

Comment: Add detail on _how_ you added the plugin. Have you followed the [instructions](https://github.com/scapegoat-scala/sbt-scapegoat#how-to-use)?

Comment: It seems that you are mixing up scapegoat's version and the version of the plugin. atm latest plugin version seems to be `1.1.1`.